# Regular Expression to find last name in "Firstname Lastname, Credentials" format

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find the last name from full names with trailing credentials. Some names have middle names or initials, hyphenated names, multiple credentials, and some have no trailing credentials:

- John Doe, MD
- Jane X. Doe, FNP-C
- Joe Cool, MD, PhD
- Billie-Jo Last

I've started with

```
/\w+(?=[\s,]+\S*$)/gmi
```

which gets the last names of the first 2 formattings, but picks up the 1st credential and first name of the second 2 formattings, respectively.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Just don't - attempting to process names is a sure path to madness (or corrupted name information - one of the two) : http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You can't. Imagine names like: "Steve Allan Smith", "Steve Smith Eriksson" and "Steve Allan Smith Eriksson". How would you determine which name is the first, middle and last? All double names don't have hyphens. It does even get _more_ complex when you realize that all people don't have English names (so the format can be totally different).

Comment: Thank you — in this case, I'm not taking random input from users, it's a list of medical providers at my employer. I know all the names are English and follow a common format, with a few outliers.

Comment: If you are 100% confident that they all follow the format you posted, simply explode the string on `,`. The first element in the response is the name, which you can explode on space. Then you have all the names separated. If it contains two names, then you have the first and last. If you have three, then first, middle and last.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's the best advice - you should write it as an answer. I wrote a community-wiki answer for your comment (it's not my rep to gain).  Feel free to write your own answer - and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100% confident that they all follow the format you posted, you can do this per row (per person):

```
// Get the names part of the string
$parts = exlode(',', $nameString);

// The first element is the names.
// Now, split the name string to get the names
$names = explode(' ', $parts[0]);

$first  = $names[0];
$middle = null;
$last   = null;

if (count($names) == 2) {
    // We only have two names, which probably means that
    // the second is the last name
    $last = $names[1];
}

if (count($names) == 3) {
    // We got three names, let's assume that the second is the middle name
    $middle = $names[1];

    // And the third is the last name
    $last = $names[2];
}
```

The above code can be optimized, but I wanted to make it as self explanatory as possible.

**Note:** This only works for the names that follows the format you mentioned. If you were to get more than three names, you have a problem since you won't be able to determine if it is a double first, middle or last name.

Answer (score 1):

If all your input is well structured as you described, then the best advice is to do what @Magnus Eriksson stated in his commend.  The code is extremely simple:

```
$parts = explode(',', $inputString);
$names = explode(' ', trim($parts[0]));
$lastName = $names[count($names) - 1];
```

Comment: Well... I was WAY overthinking this. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @pixleight No worries.  You really should accept MagnusEricsson 's answer instead of this one now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no worries

Comment: Thanks to both of you; big help.